# Can SCORM store multiple results?

Tags: standards, scorm

I was wondering wether SCORM can store multiple scores of a SCO. I have read many articles and same state it can't, and when I restart a SCO it erases the previous score, other articles sais the opposite. How is it? Maybe the 1.2 can't, and the 2004 version can?

Answer (score 0):

Well...it's complicated. You *can* restart a SCO, but it wipes the tracking data and score and starts fresh.

From the SCORM 2004 4th ed docs:

> **4.2.8. Exit**
>
> The cmi.exit data model element indicates how or why the learner left the SCO [1].
> This value is used to indicate the reason
> that the SCO was last exited.  The cmi.exit data model element is
> involved with temporal aspects of the run-time execution of the SCO.
>
> • If the cmi.exit is set to “suspend” then the SCOs current learner
> attempt does not end.  The SCOs Run-Time Environment data model
> element values for the current learner session will be available to
> the SCO if the SCO is relaunched in a subsequent learner session.
>
> • If the cmi.exit is set to “normal”, “logout”,“time-out” or “” (empty
> characterstring) then the SCOs learner attempt ends.  The SCOs
> Run-Time Environment data model element values of the current learner
> session will NOT be available if the SCO is relaunched.
>
> **ADL Note:** If an LMS invokes a Suspend All navigation request, then the value of
> cmi.exit will be ignored.  In these cases, the SCOs current learner
> attempt does not end.  The SCO’s data model element values shall be
> persisted and available to the SCO if the SCO is relaunched.

But if you want to allow learners to have multiple scores for the same SCO, that isn't supported in the SCORM standard as far as I know. It doesn't mean that the LMS couldn't offer such a feature, though, to create "pseudo-learners" that map to the same person, letting you keep multiple attempts. Or, if your LMS has an API or supports webhooks, you could also create your own separate datastore that records scores, so that if the SCO gets wiped and restarted you can still keep the historical data on your own. You would need to check with your LMS vendor to see if either of those options would be supported.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into interactions.  That gives you greater ability to journal or update the activities/questions/interactions of your content.  That will also enable you to set the result, latency and other values per interaction.

SCORM 1.2 was mostly an optionally supported standard but it did support it.  SCORM 2004 made it mandatory so its more likely you'll have the support.

There is a lot of wiki based info on this located here: https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki/SCORM-SCOBot-Documentation#set-interaction

Just remember the SCOBot Content API is a javascript library to interface the LMS Runtime API. It includes the roll-up of the white paper so it's easier to work with all facets of the SCORM Specification.  It is obviously not a replacement for reading the specification.

I also recognize you may be asking about attempts here.  That would be up to the LMS to record that.  SCORM does not make any direct restrictions if the LMS does/does not do that or is required to.